# Why my global loader interceptor is not working correctly in angular12?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `interceptor` whose job is just to show loader when http request starts and hide when http request ends. So for that I tried this so far

loader.interceptor.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

 constructor(private _us: UtilService) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  this._us.showLoader();
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    finalize(() => this._us.hideLoader())
  );
 }
}
```

util.service.ts

```
  isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  showLoader() {
    this.isLoading.next(true);
    console.log(this.isLoading.value);
  }

  hideLoader() {
    this.isLoading.next(false);
  }
```

layout.componet.html

```
<div class="wrapper w-100">
   <cl-spinner [show]="isLoading"></cl-spinner>
<!-- Navbar -->
<app-header></app-header>
<!-- /.navbar -->

<!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper p-3">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<!-- Main Footer -->
  <app-footer></app-footer>

 <!-- Control Sidebar -->
 <app-control-sidebar></app-control-sidebar>
 <!-- /.control-sidebar -->

</div>
```

layout.component.ts

```
ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.us.isLoading.subscribe((val: any) => {
      console.log('value from subscriber : ',val)
      if (val != this.isLoading) {
        this.isLoading = val;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
   });
}
```

spinner.component.html

```
 <div class="cl-loader-wrapper" *ngIf="show">
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="spinner-border loader-content"  role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

spinner.copmonent.ts

```
  @Input() show: boolean;
```

It's printing like this in console

[image]

but the problem is that it's not showing loader at all because inside `layout.component.ts` inside of subscriber of `isLoading` observable it always gets false value in `subscriber` but i am passing `true` to the `BehaviourSubject` of `isLoading` so it should show the loader. But still loader is not showing. Where is a miss in this flow?

Comment: I strongly believe yoru interceptor is not added to app module ?

Comment: Could you use another lifecycle hook and also not call the cdrefChange detector .. also try to throttle your network request to may be 2g speed and you'll have a clearer view of the issue here

Comment: @Crocsx it's already added in app.module.ts

Comment: @adedayojs i tried different life cycle hooks, removed cdrefChange detector and also tried throttling of network. So the result is that each time behaviour subject is returning it's intial value i.e false.

Comment: @FahadSubzwari Could you reproduce a small version of the app on stackblits or any other platform and share here?